# What's the use of ClientQuotaCallback in kafka-clients?

Tags: apache-kafka

I find this line in its Comment:"Quota callback interface for brokers that enables customization of client quota computation".but it doesnt has any child class,why?and i googled it but cant find an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kafka, it was decided to have all broker pluggable APIs as Java interfaces. For that reason, there are a few interfaces in kafka-clients that are not related to the clients. This is because the server side is actually written in Scala.

Anything under `org.apache.kafka.server` are pluggable APIs for the brokers. These can be used to customize some behaviours on the broker side:

- http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/server/policy/package-summary.html
- http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/server/quota/package-summary.html

For example, `ClientQuotaCallback` allows to customize the way quotas are calculated by Kafka brokers. For example, you can build Quotas for groups or have Quotas scale when topic/partitions are created. [KIP-257](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-257+-+Configurable+Quota+Management) details exactly how this all works.

Of course, for these to work you need to build implementation of these interfaces and put them in the classpath on your brokers. It's not something that can be used by clients directly.

Comment: thank you for your answer.by the way,Is it now possible to implement customizing quotas via available apis（something like adminClient.createTopic）instead of command line（like bin/kafka-configs.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200' --entity-type users --entity-name user1 --entity-type clients --entity-name clientA）？or I must implementation on my own ？thanks again.

Comment: kafka-configs only lets you set Quota limits whereas if you implement `ClientQuotaCallback` you can decide how the limit is applied to clients